# Please help me identify a board game!

Tags: identify-this-game

I bought the pictured board game with no instructions and can't even find what it is. Does anybody know?

[image]

Comment: One half of the board looks like the one mentioned here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38283/
The other half could maybe be for tracking score?